# Android Studio Tic Tac Toe

Tags: java, android, xml

Disclaimer, I'm a noob still.
I have no idea why c is always 9 in this loop, it supposed to be 1 and then add 1 each loop, and each number, I check to see if its a whole number, if its a whole number, I will print the symbol O, and if not ill print X.

The whole checking if the number is round or not and choosing what symbol depending on the number, works, my problem is that every iteration, the counter "c" is for some reason 9 no matter what, it doesn't even start at 1 as I told it

**JAVA**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;                   // I know I don't need all of these, it's just easier to have all here.
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }

  public void handle (View v){
      String symbol1 = "O";
      String symbol2 = "X"; 
      for (int c = 1; c < 10; c++) { // 9 iterations loop
          ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.texto)).setText("c = " + c);      // just checking what c is in each iteration.
          v.setEnabled(false);                                           // removes option to select a box.
          Button b = (Button) v;                                        //making this so I can use setText.
          if ((c % 2) == 0) {                                          // checking to see if its a whole number.
              b.setText(symbol1);                                       //if round print O in the box.
          } else b.setText(symbol2);                                   //else print X in the box.
      }
  }
}
```

**XML**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/app"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="108dp"
        android:layout_height="101dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:onClick="handle"
        android:text="INSERT"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="109dp"
        android:layout_height="101dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:onClick="handle"
        android:text="INSERT"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="108dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:onClick="handle"
        android:text="INSERT"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn4"
        android:layout_width="108dp"
        android:layout_height="102dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:onClick="handle"
        android:text="INSERT"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn5"
        android:layout_width="109dp"
        android:layout_height="101dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:onClick="handle"
        android:text="INSERT"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn6"
        android:layout_width="108dp"
        android:layout_height="103dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:onClick="handle"
        android:text="INSERT"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn7"
        android:layout_width="108dp"
        android:layout_height="101dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:onClick="handle"
        android:text="INSERT"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn8"
        android:layout_width="109dp"
        android:layout_height="101dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:onClick="handle"
        android:text="INSERT"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn9"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn7"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn9"
        android:layout_width="108dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:onClick="handle"
        android:text="INSERT"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn6" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/texto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="336dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.526"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: '9' would be the last value displayed - so unless you are using a debugger to stop it on each iteration - you'd only see the last value displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, That's logical

Your `handle` function will be executed on **each click** , that means `c` will **increase** until reached to `9` on each click **seperately**.

If you need `c` to increase by one on each click, you need to initialize `c` as global variable and change `for` loop with `if` condition only .

**solution** :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int c = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void handle (View v){
        String symbol1 = "O";
        String symbol2 = "X";
        if (c < 10){
            Log.i("TAG", "handle: c is : " + c);
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.texto)).setText("c = " + c);      // just checking what c is in each iteration.
            v.setEnabled(false);                                           // removes option to select a box.
            Button b = (Button) v;                                        //making this so I can use setText.
            if ((c % 2) == 0) {                                          // checking to see if its a whole number.
                b.setText(symbol1);                                       //if round print O in the box.
            } else b.setText(symbol2);
            c++;
        }
    }
```